# I need to ask for input on server name

Tags: python

For now, I retrieve an Output from a remote Server from the code below :

```
import subprocess 
f=open ("o.txt", 'w')
subprocess.call(["sudo", "su", "switchadm", "-c", "ssh admin@server1 switchshow"], stdout=f)
f1=open('o.txt', 'r')
f2=f1.read()
print (f2)
```

The above one displays only for server1. However, I need to ask the user for input and parse the input there in the Line 3 instead of "server1".

Comment: use `server = input("what server?")` and supply it?

Comment: `server_name = input('Server: ')` `"ssh admin@{} switchshow".format(server_name)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use input to get the server name and the format to substitute the same

Comment: Okay , thanks for ur answer . I did the same as below
serv = input('Enter server name')
subprocess.call(["sudo", "su", "switchadm", "-c", "ssh admin@{0} switchshow".format(serv)])

Answer (score 1):

Use [input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

```
server = input("Server :")
ssh_command = "ssh admin@{} switchshow".format(server)
subprocess.call(["sudo", "su", "switchadm", "-c", ssh_command], stdout=f)
```